# JPivot Display Mondrian Result

Tags: java, olap, mondrian

I am trying to display the result of a Mondrian query using JPivot. Many examples are showing how to use the tag library for JSP but I need to use the Java API, I looked at the documentation but I cannot understand how to use it to display the results in the table. Here is my code

```
Query query = connection.parseQuery(mdxQuery);
Result result = connection.execute(query);
result.print(new PrintWriter(System.out,true));
```

I would like to know if I can use the result object to build the jpivot table. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, using `JPivot`
is a pretty bad idea.
It was discontinued **back in 2008**.

There is a good project which is intended to **replace the JPivot** called [Pivot4j](http://mysticfall.github.io/pivot4j/). Despite it is currently under development (0.8 -> 0.9 version), Pivot4j can actually do the business.

**However, if we're talking about your case:**

```
result.print(new PrintWriter(System.out,true));
```

This string prints the HTML code with OLAP cube into your System.out.
You can write the HTML code in some output stream (like FileOuputStream), and then display it.

```
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("result.html");
result.print(new PrintWriter(out, true));

//then display this file in a browser
```

However, if you want to have the **same interface as in JPivot**, I don't think there is an **easy way** to do it **without .jsp**. In these case I strongly recommend you to try [Pivot4j](http://mysticfall.github.io/pivot4j/).

Good luck!